# Failed to launch Firefox 41 with Geckodriver using Selenium 3.0.0-beta3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-marionette

I was running some quick tests using `WebDriver`.  I downlowded the `FirefoxWebDriver` and the `ChromeWebDriver`; `geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64.zip` and `chromedriver_win32.zip`.

They are extracted to a path location and have been renamed accordingly; `wires.exe` and `chromedriver.exe` respectively.

When I created my test, did as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);

//WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DeesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

and for `Firefox`, it failed to create a session (and failed the tests), where-as chrome succeeded and then passed the tests.

The Output from the test is as follows:

```js
Sep 28, 2016 2:51:32 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Sep 28, 2016 2:51:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Sep 28, 2016 2:51:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:57:44 -0700'
System info: host: 'CHI-CS-55DXX52', ip: '10.60.68.15', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:231)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:219)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:214)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:131)
 at com.polymerdart.webdriver.MyFirstTest.startWebDriver(MyFirstTest.java:21)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:57:44 -0700'
System info: host: 'CHI-CS-55DXX52', ip: '10.60.68.15', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:597)
 ... 34 more
```

I do see `Firefox` opening, but it just fails to create the session and the closes.  I am currently running on this machine `Firefox version 41.0`

Comment: Try as `WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);` instead and let me know

Comment: @SaurabhGaur It says "unreachable browser exception"  Maybe that is because I updated the filename of the updated firefox from gecko to wires.  As a side note, IntelliJ says the MarionetteDriver is depricated.

Comment: Which version of selenium and Firefox are you using??

Comment: Firefox 41, Selenium 3.0.0-beta3

Comment: Ah, thats is the problem, actually latest selenium support geckodriver to launch firefox, and geckodriver support only >= v47 of firefox version, so you need to upgrade your firefox browser as well or downgrade selenium version to `selenium2`. Thank

Comment: So if i want to test on various versions of Firefox, i will have to have different versions of selenium running different tests?  That kinda weird.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's weird but this is happened after Mozilla provided executable geckodriver to support latest firefox with selenium just like other driver. Thank

Comment: I am doing some tests to confirm that the Firefox update to >= 47 is the answer.  I will post a confirmation or new info shortly.

Comment: Confirmed.   Mozilla Firefox v47.1 works with Selenium 3.0.0-beta3, BUT it  doesnt work with 3 line the code snippet I supplied in the question. Now you just need `WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());`

Comment: Nothing do special with selenium 3 after upgrading firefox just simply call `new FirefoxDriver()` after setting system property with geckodriver driver as suggested answer and it would work. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the incapability issue between `Selenium3` and `Mozilla Firefox` version.

Actually `Selenium3` supports executable [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to launch `Mozilla Firefox` just like other driver now but executable [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) compatible with [`Mozilla Firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/), that's why you're in trouble.

There are two work around to get rid from this issue :-

- Downgrade your selenium version to [`Selenium2`](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) as well.
- Upgrade your [`Mozilla Firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) as well and try with `Selenium3` and launching `FirefoxDriver` as below :-

  ```
  //Set system property with downloaded executable geckodriver from your system location 

  DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
  ```

Comment: When doing tests right now, doing it without `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()` will cause it to fail for me.  Just so you know.  I kept it in there.

Comment: It also works  directly
 `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`